# Redirect Users to New Record

Tags: apex, redirect

Basically, I am creating a record type called 'Pre Opportunity'. When a user moves this opp to the stage 'Rescheduling', I am creating a new 'Pre Opportunity' record. I want to redirect the users to this new record after they move the stage to 'Redirect'. Is it possible to redirect users to a new URL after they update a record? This is not a visual force page.

```
public with sharing class DemoRescheduling 

public static void handleTrigger(List<Opportunity> newOpps) 
{

    Set<Id> preOpptyIds = new Set<Id>();

    List<Opportunity> cloned_opps = new List<Opportunity>();

    for(Opportunity opp: newOpps)
    {
        if(opp.StageName == 'Rescheduling' && opp.RecordTypeId  == '0126A000000yudDQAQ' && opp.RescheduledOppCreated__c == false)
        {
            preOpptyIds.add(opp.Id);

            String name = opp.Previous_Demo__c == null ? 'Rescheduled Demo: ' + opp.Name : opp.Name;

            Opportunity clonedOpp = opp.clone(false, true, false);
            clonedOpp.StageName = 'Demo Set';
            clonedOpp.Name = name;
            clonedOpp.Demo_Date_Time__c = opp.Reschedule_Demo_Date_Time__c;
            clonedOpp.Demo_Date__c = opp.Reschedule_Demo_Date_Time__c.date();
            clonedOpp.CloseDate = opp.Reschedule_Demo_Date_Time__c.date() + 1;
            clonedOpp.Previous_Demo__c = opp.Id;
            clonedOpp.Reschedule_Demo_Date_Time__c = null;
            cloned_opps.add(clonedOpp);
            opp.RescheduledOppCreated__c = true;
        }
    }


    if(cloned_opps.size() > 0)
    {
        insert cloned_opps;




        List<OpportunityContactRole> oppCons = [SELECT OpportunityId, ContactId, isPrimary FROM OpportunityContactRole WHERE OpportunityId in :preOpptyIds];

        List<OpportunityContactRole> clonedOppCons = new List<OpportunityContactRole>();

        for(OpportunityContactRole oppCon : oppCons)
        {
            for(Opportunity clone: cloned_opps)
            {
                if(oppCon.OpportunityId == clone.Previous_Demo__c)
                {
                    OpportunityContactRole clonedOppCon = oppCon.clone(false, true, false);
                    clonedOppCon.OpportunityId = clone.Id;


                    clonedOppCons.add(clonedOppCon);
                }
            }
        }

        insert clonedOppCons;       
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to redirect users to a new URL after they update a record? This is not a visual force page.

No. A trigger may not even be executing in a context that has a UI session associated with it, and if it is, it can't *per se* reach into the user's browser and initiate UI activity.

You'd be able to do this only if you were in control of the UI session, via a Lightning component or a Visualforce page. You cannot do it from a trigger.